# Keras: Using use_multiprocessing=True in predict_generator gives more predictions than required?

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, keras

I am working on Language Modeling problem and using predict_generator function because of the memory issue. The problem I am facing is predict_generator gives more predictions than size of the of the input.

Parameters I am providing in predict_generator function:

```
predictions = model.predict_generator(testDataGenerator(statements),
                                                  use_multiprocessing=True,workers=4,
                                                  steps=25,
                                                  verbose=1)
```

Generator Function:

```
def testDataGenerator(testDataFrame):
        testDataFrame.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        startPoint = 0
        endPoint = 64
        while True:
            statementSet = testDataFrame[startPoint:endPoint]
            test = buildTrainAndTestSets(statementSet)
            startPoint = endPoint
            endPoint += 64
            yield test
```

I have total of 1568 inputs and I'm sending them in a batch of 64 but I'm getting 1600 predictions. The error output is:

```
25/25 [==============================] - 47s 2s/step
IndexError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I think the way I am sending the statements in the generator function in the problem here.

Comment: Do you have the full code? It's kind of hitting in the dark without seeing the where is problem might occur.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom generator you must have some caution with the last step on your predictor.

Since you are doing 25 steps with a 64 batch size, the generator expects your data to be exactly 1600, I think a simple **if** in your generator to change the endpoint should fix your problem.